# Raspberry Pi read Sound spectrum and volume of current played sound

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, usb, codec, spectrum

I am using my Raspberry Pi as a bluetooth-Speaker in combination with a GUI attached on the Raspberry. I would like to read out the current played spectrum and volume so i can display these waveforms on the GUI of my raspberry Pi. I do not use the analog audio output of the raspberry, I use a USB-Codec with an audio amplifier.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Thanks, Manuel